# llenar un select con mysql e iniciar en un valor definido

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, html-select

Buenas tardes mi duda es la siguiente, como puedo indicarle a un select en que valor iniciar ya dado una query de mysql es decir el select lo estoy llenando con datos que tengo en una db, pero iniciar en el primer valor de la db y lo que quiero es hacer que inicie en otro ya que al momento de mandar los datos de la empresa a actualizar este ya viene definido con su estado registrado  y ese mismo requiero que aparezca como seleccionado y que el usuario ya despues pueda cambiarlo de ser necesario, claro que tiene que mandar la lista de todos los estados de la republica, alguna idea de como se podria implementar, este es mi codigo  referente a la funcion que manda las consutas

```
function indexUpdateBusinessData($id_empresa,$id_direccion)
{
    $result=DB::table('empresa')
    ->join('direccion','direccion.Id_Direccion','=','empresa.Id_Direccion')
    ->join('estado','estado.Id_Estado','=','direccion.Id_Estado')
    ->join('municipio','municipio.Id_Municipio','=','direccion.Id_Municipio')
    ->join('cp','cp.Id_Cp','=','direccion.Id_Cp')
    ->where('empresa.Id_Empresa','=',$id_empresa)
    ->where('direccion.Id_Direccion','=',$id_direccion)
    ->select('empresa.Id_Empresa','empresa.Nombre','empresa.Telefono','empresa.Extension','empresa.Email','empresa.Giro','empresa.Giro_Especifico','empresa.Razon_Social','cp.Cp')
    ->get();

    $estados=DB::table('estado')
    ->select('Nombre_Estado')
    ->get();
    return view("update_information.update_business",compact("result","estados"));
}
```

esta es la parte en donde lleno el select

```
 <div class="form-group linea">
            <label>Estado</label><br>
            <select id="Estado" name="Nombre_Estado" class="redondeado">
                @foreach($estados as $e)

                <option value="">{{$e->Nombre_Estado}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
```

ahi estoy llenando el select con todos los estados pero como le indico que quiero iniciar en uno de ellos en especifico ? y que ahi el user pueda moverse y cambiarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz la validacion dentro del select, me imagino que tienes almacenado el estado de procedencia entonces lo puedes comparar haciendo algo asi:

```
@foreach($estados as $e)
    @if(Auth::user()->estado == $e->Nombre_estado) {!!Aqui yo lo haria por ID para que sea mas exacto!!}
        <option value="{!!Aqui tambien pondria el id del estado!!}" selected>{{$e->Nombre_Estado}}</option>
    @else
        <option value="{!!Aqui tambien pondria el id del estado!!}">{{$e->Nombre_Estado}}</option>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Esa seria la manera mas rapida de hacerlo

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono, un saludo crack